# TSQL Function Two substrings to new Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring

Using T-Sql I need to take substring (title1) from a column and move it to another column and then the second substring (title2) divided by ' ' to its own column as well. I was thinking using something similar to mysqls' SUBSTRING_INDEX but cant find its alias in TSQL...

edit:

It is actually bit more complicated since I need to compare the first substring with a list and if present then move this title to appropriate column, then jump to other substring and do the same.

i am using MSSMS

explanation and possible variations (title1 belongs to its column an vice versa):

```
------
col1      
------
mr. MA.
mrs. MS.   
mr.           

miss
BA.      
MA.
```

**I want to have the following result**:

```
------------------
title1   title2   
------------------
mr.       MA.  
mrs.      MS.
mr.         

miss         
          BA.
          MA.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: First we need a sample of the table, second we need a sample of what is the expected result, third show us everything you've done so far.

Comment: How do you expect to differentiate the last four values? What tells you that `BA.` and `MA.` belongs on the second column?

Comment: probably a comparison table or preferably a simple list (there will be certain number of values which i can easily name - i.e. all academy titles)... same goes for column title1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the desired result is with a couple of joins to a map table, using `Substring`, `CharIndex`, and a trick with `IsNull` and `NullIf` instead of `case`.

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Map AS TABLE
(
    Val varchar(10),
    Col int
)
INSERT INTO @Map (Val, Col) VALUES
('mr.', 1), ('mrs.', 1), ('miss', 1), 
('MA.', 2), ('MS.', 2), ('BA.', 2)

DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Col1 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T (Col1) VALUES
('mr. MA.'), ('mrs. MS.'), ('mr.'), 
('miss'), ('BA.'), ('MA.')
```

The query:

```
SELECT Col1,
        CASE WHEN M1.Col = 1 THEN M1.Val END As Title1,
        CASE WHEN M2.Col = 2 THEN M2.Val END As Title2
FROM @T AS t 
JOIN @Map AS M1
    ON M1.Val = SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', Col1), 0), LEN(Col1)))
JOIN @Map AS M2
    ON M2.Val = SUBSTRING(Col1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', Col1), 0), 0) + 1, LEN(Col1))
```

Results:

```
Col1      |   Title1  |   Title2
mr. MA.   |   mr.     |   MA.
mrs. MS.  |   mrs.    |   MS.
mr.       |   mr.     |   NULL
miss      |   miss    |   NULL
BA.       |   NULL    |   BA.
MA.       |   NULL    |   MA.
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/XLD45628)

Comment: thank you a lot! works like a charm. next time ill try to post more complete query here, this was my first time.

Comment: Glad to help :-)